# Wampserver acusando aviso (Warning) com virtual host

Tags: php, wamp, virtualhost, wampserver, password

Criei um **virtual host** no [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/), no localhost não acusa aviso nenhum no `console`, mas com outro(s) **virtual host** é acusado o seguinte aviso:

> This page includes a password or credit card input in a non-secure
>   context. A warning has been added to the URL bar. For more
>   information, see [Link que não consegui adicionar aqui](https://security.googleblog.com/2016/09/moving-towards-more-secure-web.html).

Qual a solução pra retirar este aviso?

OBS: Só aparece este aviso ao adicionar um `input type="password"`, não suporto ver *avisos* e *erros* no `console`.

**EDIT 1**

o domínio é este: `http://mef.host/`

Comment: Vc envia essas informações via get?

Comment: Não Não apenas estou fazendo isso: http://prntscr.com/fy1bvr, mas ja tentei  `GET` e `POST` mesma coisa, só no virtual_host que acontece isso, em localhost padrão não acontece.

Comment: @rray sabe a solução. até agora não consegui arrumar.

Comment: Isso você vai resolver só quando hospedar o site, usar SSL, e certificado. no server local o warning não some, por não ter SSL e certificado ativo.